# Vertex Shader Input Order

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

Does input order for a SM 4.0 vertex shader matter?

e.g. is

```
struct App2VS
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
        ...
};
```

equivalent to

```
struct App2VS
{
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
        ...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it shouldn't matter.  The mapping information is performed by the Input Layout.

Essentially the input layout maps a given struct element to a specific input "register".  These input registers are then used to load the struct used by HLSL.  The HLSL struct is not a real memory mapping as those input register (ie POSITION or COLOR0) are not actual memory locations.

Comment: Thought so. Do you know in what situations a different ordering could cause different behaviors though? It works with {position, color, } in the HLSL but if I change it to {color, position, } in the HLSL color values are used as position. (No changes in the C++ input layout/vertex declaration)

Comment: Fixed it... I was unknowingly sharing an InputLayout :(